# Same Code, Different Computers - Counterintuitive and HUGE Differences in Performance

Tags: performance, cpu

TL;DR: I'm doing some performance computing, and I've found that the ostensibly 'weaker' machine is outperforming the 'stronger' machine by orders of magnitude. Why?

I wrote some C code for a project. It involves 10,000 iterations of a lengthy process that generates pseudorandom data, and after each iteration, writes the data to a file. I used `#pragma omp parallel for` to multi-thread the task.

I can run my program on two machines: let's call them **s** and **d**. Here are the relevant specs (please ask for any other specs that might matter):

- **s**: Linux Mint 15, Samsung 840 EVO SSD, 8gB RAM, quad-core Intel i3 CPU @ 2.40 gHZ
- **d**: Linux Mint 16, Intel SSD, 8gB RAM, eight-core AMD FX-8320 CPU @ 3.5 gHZ

Here's the big surprise: **s** completes the task an order of magnitude faster than **d**. I've run the program a few times on both machines, and **s** completes the task in about 3-4 minutes, whereas **d** takes anywhere from 12 to upwards of 30 minutes (I lost track of time). Both of them fully exhaust their cores (i.e. all cores at 100%) while computing. This phenomenon is even with auxiliary programs (Firefox, etc.) open on **s**, and nothing else running on **d**.

But the code is the same. The compiler flags are the same. Even the output is the same. I even removed the drives from both **s** and **d**, and swapped them and then ran the program again, just to test that it wasn't in some way Operating-System related. The result was that the phenomenon persisted: the quad-core 2.4 gHZ CPU vastly outperformed the eight-core 3.5 gHZ CPU.

This is, of course, really puzzling and totally counterintuitive. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: Get a profiler and measure.

Comment: Amdahl's law and that different systems will do the sequential fraction at a different speed in addition to the parallel portion.

Comment: Are you sure the Intel processor is an i3 and four *cores*? Even for 4th gen. i3, [the ark](http://ark.intel.com/products/family/75025/4th-Generation-Intel-Core-i3-Processors/) only shows 2-core versions; perhaps you meant Xeon **E3**? (If it is only 4 *threads*, this would make the comparison even more skewed.) A 4x performance difference does seem odd. SPEC CPU2006 FP Rate results for higher performance but "similar" systems (AMD FX-8150 vs. Intel Xeon E3-1220--34% Intel advantage) seem to imply that the Intel system should be **roughly** "only" 10-15% faster.

Comment: Also, are you sure that they are *executing* the same code? A portable binary might include multiple code paths to support different systems and the selection might be suboptimal for the AMD system (the Intel C compiler used to have this kind of issue).

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton according to my system diagnostics, the intel processor has four cores. Here's a screenshot: http://imgur.com/fYKceHe You have a good point with regard to the execution of code: perhaps the selection is suboptimal for the AMD processor. What can I do about this? How can I test this? Is there a different compiler I can use? (I'm using GCC at the moment.)

Comment: [That processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/49020/Intel-Core-i3-370M-Processor-3M-cache-2_40-GHz) has 2 *cores* but 4 virtual processors (a.k.a. threads). That makes the performance difference look even more bizarre. For gcc you might try "-march=bdver2" for the AMD system, but a roughly 6x difference from expectations seems **odd** (~4x performance difference, ~1.35x μarch difference, ~2x core count). "-march=native" can be a convenient option for **system-specific** binaries where target=local; "-mtune=" provides more broadly compatible but specifically tuned binaries.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is the Megahertz Myth, a bigger number doesn't always mean better because actual computational speed is dependent on architecture and design factors. [Here's a nice webpage on the issue.](http://www.geek.com/chips/why-amd-mhz-dont-equal-intel-mhz-557914/)

Comment: The AMD processor also is a design somewhat between simultaneous multithreading and traditional multicore. Two "cores" form a module which share a front-end (and FP/SIMD functionality) but with separate integer execution and L1 data caches. I.e., there is also a "core myth" effect.